# What is the origin of Kula Devata or Family Deity?

Tags: religion, indian

In India, every house has something called Kula Devata or Family Deity. What is the historical reason for having such Family deity, and on what basis are family deities assigned to families? Is there any historical, ancestral or political connection between the Deity and the family that worships it? Does it have any relation to the region in which the Deity resides? As I see, there is no strict caste specific restriction on having a particular Deity as your Kula Devata. Can anyone here shed light on this, or mention similar practices being followed elsewhere in the world/other religions?

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suited to Hinduism SE?

Comment: I am expecting answers from a history point of view rather than a philosohical or mithological point of view, so I think it is apt to b posted here

Comment: Many scholars claim that the practice of maintaining household deities around the world can be traced back to ancestor veneration. This practice is not limited to Hinduism and was quite common in many Indo-European and Mesopotamian traditions.

Comment: @called2voyage Do you mean, ancestor veneration means, worshiping of ancestors as deities? That is different from what I am referring to as Family Deities. Ex: There is a temple of Lord Balaji in South India, and a lot of South Indian families have the same deity as family deity

Comment: @Sushant Ok, that is a little outside of my experience. I can't be sure, but it is possible that sharing a deity devotion as a family is related to household deities, in which case the roots may be the same, but I'll defer to those who know more on the topic at hand.

Comment: @Sushant [This article](http://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/37852883/Caste_on_the_Hill.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ56TQJRTWSMTNPEA&Expires=1467919140&Signature=%2F2z9T3ywDsv449y8uyDaIAVIHIY%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DSPECIAL_ARTICLE_Cast_e_on_the_Hill_Divin.pdf) claims that two possible origins are 1) devatas are incarnations of Hindu gods/goddess or 2) devatas are deceased rajas or princes. Based on the description, though, I'd say that an origin in ancestor veneration is still likely.

Comment: @called2voyage link not working

Comment: @Sushant Unfortunately, it looks like it's been removed from the web. I should have added it to the Internet Archive when I had the chance.

Answer (score -1):

Please start reading this link which airs ten part article on Kula devatha or tutelary/family deities. You will get answers to Kula Devatha concept.

https://santhipriya.com/2022/04/kula-devatha-or-tutelary-family-deities-1.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).